# Difference between `registerTempTable` and `createTempView` in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to spark and going through the data frame operations.

As per given in documentation of Apache Spark `registerTempTable` and `createTempView` looks similar a lot.

Can anyone tell what exactly is the difference between the `registerTempTable` and `createTempView`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `registerTempTable` method has been deprecated in spark 2.0.0+ and it internally calls `createOrReplaceTempView`. `Dataset` object-

```
 private[sql] object Dataset {

 /**
   * Registers this Dataset as a temporary table using the given name. The lifetime of this
   * temporary table is tied to the [[SparkSession]] that was used to create this Dataset.
   *
   * @group basic
   * @since 1.6.0
   */
  @deprecated("Use createOrReplaceTempView(viewName) instead.", "2.0.0")
  def registerTempTable(tableName: String): Unit = {
    createOrReplaceTempView(tableName)
  }

............
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is the description of the both.

```
def createTempView(viewName: String): Unit

Creates a local temporary view using the given name. The lifetime of this 
temporary view is tied to the SparkSession that was used to create this Dataset

def registerTempTable(tableName: String): Unit

Registers this Dataset as a temporary table using the given name. The 
lifetime of this temporary table is tied to the SparkSession that was used to create this Dataset.
```

[image]

From the image you can see registerTempTable is deprecated in Spark 2.0. Means registerTempTable  was the feature prior to Spark 2.0.

Comment: your answer is also correct I only upvote the answer now